I'm struggling to understand what 'such money as I had' means here. I am also wondering about the omission of 'to' after 'ought' in final position

There I stayed for some time at a private hotel in the  Strand, leading a comfortless, meaningless existence, and spending such money as I had, considerably more freely than I ought.

I have two questions about this excerpt from A Study in Scarlet. Firstly, what exactly does 'such' mean? My best guess would be that it means something akin to 'like' or 'that'. I recognise it somehow has the impact of making evident that the amount of money he had is small, but what exactly does 'such' mean there? Other sentences that employ the word in a similar manner would be appreciated.
My other question would be about how acceptable the omission of 'to have' is there. I recognise that often in negative and interrogative clauses, the 'to' following 'ought' is dropped, as in:


You ought not to do that.
Ought we to go now?


But I've also noticed sentences that are neither interrogative nor negative with the 'to' missing that regardless do not sound very wrong to my intuition (though I am a non-native so it can be faulty at times). What they typically have in common is 'ought' being at the end of the phrase. Here are some examples I've come up with, besides the one I've provided above:


I often drink much more than I ought, and I go on to regret it every time.
I stared at him for a trifle longer than I ought.
They would steal from the houses of the poor, and I would try to stop them, as I thought I ought.


I was also wondering whether 'ought to have' can also be omitted in such a way. In the quote from A Study in Scarlet, it seems to me that not only was 'to' omitted but also 'have' (my second example sentence also does this). Does that have any effect on how natural the omission is? Is this omission a mistake? Would such an omission be acceptable in other positions that aren't phrase-final?
I'd like to emphasise that I mean dropping 'to' and the following verb in positive declarative sentences where there isn't a contraction with the 'ought'. I'm aware the 'to' can be dropped when the sentence is negative or a question.

It was written in 1887, 137 years ago.

This answers your second question: Is it appropriate to omit "to" after "ought"?

@fev, the passage you linked to talks about negatives and contractions. It also mentions dropping the verb after but doesn't really mention anything about dropping 'to' in positive declarative sentences with no contractions. The example they give, 'Yes, we ought to', retains the 'to' despite dropping the verb. I did look at that question before posting my own and found it not to be exactly the same situation.

The second, totally distinct, question is similar to: Is it appropriate to omit "to" after "ought"?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

'Such money as I had' = 'what [little] money I had'.
Yes, it's perfectly OK to omit 'to have [done]' after 'ought', as in your three examples. The meaning is clear without it.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. (Though the paraphrase is spot on.) The 'Such N as' quantifier equivalent of 'What[ever] N' is interesting. // (The second, totally distinct, question is a duplicate.)

Yes, but one wouldn't use it today. It's quasi-archaic.

I couldn't find a suitable definition of such online, and I don't have access to the OED.

There are plenty of attestations  of ...than I ought. from the last 50 years, and though the style of writing is usually conservative and tends towards the formal, it's not an archaism by any means.

such has a concessive sense, expressing the notion that something is not as much as it should be, or as grand, or that it lacks some quality one might expect it to have or that it should have.  Welcome to our home, such as it is. It was a fixer-upper, and we've still a long way to go.  or  We called on such strength as we had left and gave it one last effort.
